# Webdrivercss make a whole page screenshot

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have little problem with making screenshot of whole page. Using webdriverio code such this (below, with firefox) makes me screenshot of whole page, but not with chrome. Author api says, that i need to use webdrivercss, but i dont know how. Anybody, pls help me. How i can change that code.

```
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
var options = {
    desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome'
    }
};
var size;
webdriverio
    .remote(options)
    .init()
    .windowHandleMaximize(false)
    .url('http://webdriver.io/')
    .saveScreenshot('./chrome.png')
    .end();
```

For every help, i will be grateful

Comment: did you find any issue in the example from webdrivercss documentation (https://github.com/webdriverio/webdrivercss) ?

Comment: I tried, but no. I dont have idea how to encahnce webdriverio to webdrivercss.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example:

```
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
var webdrivercss = require('webdrivercss');
var options = {
  desiredCapabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome'
  }
};

var browser = webdriverio.remote(options);

webdrivercss.init(browser, {
  screenshotRoot: './',
  screenWidth: [1024]
});

client.init()
  .windowHandleMaximize(false)
  .url('http://webdriver.io/')
  .webdrivercss('chrome-screenshot', {
    name:'some_id',
    elem:'body'
  }, function(err, res){}))
  .saveScreenshot('chrome-screenshot')
  .end();
```

For more information view the [webdrivercss](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdrivercss) github. The documentation is lovely.
I've had trouble with screenshots through the chromedriver. They don't render properly... but phantomjs worked well.